# Remove first encountered elements from a list

Tags: python, list

I have two Python lists with the same number of elements. The elements of the first list are unique, the ones in the second list - not necessarily so. For instance

```
list1 = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6', 'e7']
list2 = ['h1', 'h2', 'h1', 'h3', 'h1', 'h2', 'h4']
```

I want to remove all the "first encountered" elements from the second list and their corresponding elements from the first list. Basically, this means removing all unique elements *and* the first element of the duplicates. With the above example, the correct result should be

```
>>>list1
['e3', 'e5', 'e6']
>>>list2
['h1', 'h1', 'h2']
```

That is, the element 'e1' was removed because its corresponding 'h1' was encountered for the first time, 'e2' was removed because 'h2' was seen for the first time, 'e3' was left because 'h1' was already seen, 'e4' was removed because 'h3' was seen for the first time, 'e5' was left because 'h1' was already seen, 'e6' was left because 'h2' was already seen, and 'e7' was removed because 'h4' was seen for the first time.

What would be an efficient way to solve this problem? The lists could contain thousands of elements, so I'd rather not make duplicates of them or run multiple loops, if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a `set` object to lookup if the current value is already seen, like this

```
>>> list1 = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6', 'e7']
>>> list2 = ['h1', 'h2', 'h1', 'h3', 'h1', 'h2', 'h4']
>>>
>>> def filterer(l1, l2):
...     r1 = []
...     r2 = []
...     seen = set()
...     for e1, e2 in zip(l1, l2):
...         if e2 not in seen:
...             seen.add(e2)
...         else:
...             r1.append(e1)
...             r2.append(e2)
...     return r1, r2
...
>>> list1, list2 = filterer(list1, list2)
>>> list1
['e3', 'e5', 'e6']
>>> list2
['h1', 'h1', 'h2']
```

---

If you are going to consume the elements one-by-one and if the input lists are pretty big, then I would recommend making a generator, like this

```
>>> def filterer(l1, l2):
...     seen = set()
...     for e1, e2 in zip(l1, l2):
...         if e2 not in seen:
...             seen.add(e2)
...         else:
...             yield e1, e2
...
>>> list(filterer(list1, list2))
[('e3', 'h1'), ('e5', 'h1'), ('e6', 'h2')]
>>>
>>> zip(*filterer(list1, list2))
[('e3', 'e5', 'e6'), ('h1', 'h1', 'h2')]
```

Comment: Wouldn't your first example create almost complete copies (minus the first element) of both lists in the worst case (i.e., the second list contains copies of one and the same element)? And `zip()` would create yet another list of tuples from the corresponding elements of each list. I was hoping to avoid that and edit the lists in place (i.e., delete the unnecessary elements).

Comment: @bontchev: Deleting an element near the beginning of a list is almost as expensive as making a brand new copy of the whole thing!

Answer (score 10):

I might be code golfing here but I find this interesting:

```
list1_new = [x for i, x in enumerate(list1) if list2[i] in list2[:i]]
print(list1_new)
# prints ['e3', 'e5', 'e6']
```

What happens here in case you are not familiar with list comprehensions is the following (reading it from the end):

- I am checking whether element `i` of `list2` exists in a slicing of `list2` that includes all previous elements `list2[:i]`.
- if it does then I capture the corresponding element from `list1` (`x`) and I store it in the new list I am creating `list1_new`

Comment: This has quadratic run time. Not exactly what I understand as "efficient".

Comment: I don't think that it is very important for such a task. Even if the original lists have thousands of entries, the difference in run time should be milliseconds but as i state above, i posted my take on it as an interesting one not as the most efficient.

Comment: this answer was linked in comments in code golf stack exchange https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223527/remove-first-encountered-elements-from-a-second-list

Answer (score 7):

An efficient way would be to use a `set`, which contains all already seen keys. A `set` will guarantee you an average lookup of `O(1)`.

So something like this should work:

```
s = set()
result1 = []
result2 = []
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    if y in s:
        result1.append(x)
        result2.append(y)
    else:
        s.add(y)
```

Notice, this will create a new list. Shouldn't be a big problem though, since Python doesn't actually copy the strings, but only creates a pointer to the original string.

Answer (score 4):

Use a set to keep track of values you've already encountered:

```
seen= set()
index= 0
while index < len(list1):
    i1, i2= list1[index], list2[index]
    if i2 in seen:
        index+= 1
    else:
        seen.add(i2)
        del list1[index]
        del list2[index]
```

Answer (score 4):

From a comment:

> I was hoping to avoid that and edit the lists in place

I don't really advise doing this unless your code actually is running out of memory (or you reasonably expect that it will), but it's certainly possible:

```
seen = set()
toidx = 0
for first, second in itertools.izip(list1, list2):
    if second in seen:
        list1[toidx] = first
        list2[toidx] = second
        toidx += 1
    else:
        seen.add(second)
del seen
del list1[toidx:]
del list2[toidx:]
```

Fans of C++ will recognise this as the erase-remove idiom.

The `del` might make a copy of the part of the list you're keeping, but at least it does them one at a time instead of needing to have all five collections in memory simultaneously (two input lists, two output lists, and the set `seen`).

There's no way to truncate a list without that copy being a possibility, so you could instead leave the lists at their full size but remember how many values are usable. In that case you should probably set the unusable values at the end to `None`, so that any removed elements which aren't referenced from elsewhere can be freed.

> The lists could contain thousands of elements

If you're using a real computer, as opposed to some microscopic machine etched onto the head of a pin, then thousands of elements is nothing. A list requires approximately 8 bytes per element. Storing the same object in multiple lists doesn't need a copy of the object. So, using two extra lists for the outputs will occupy something of the order of 16 bytes per pair of inputs: 160kB for 10k elements. For scale, the browser I'm writing this answer on is currently using 1GB of RAM. Getting off SO while it runs is a far greater memory optimization than modifying the lists in place ;-)

Reducing memory usage can help with cache performance, though. And if you have hundreds of millions of elements, then in-place modification could be the difference between your code running or failing.

Comment: +1 for 'If you're using a real computer, as opposed to some microscopic machine etched onto the head of a pin, then thousands of elements is nothing.'.  Without knowing more, this seems like premature optimisation.

Answer (score 3):

You an try :

```
>>> list1 = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6', 'e7']
>>> list2 = ['h1', 'h2', 'h1', 'h3', 'h1', 'h2', 'h4']
>>> repeat = list(set([x for x in list2 if list2.count(x) > 1]))
>>> print repeat 
['h2', 'h1']
>>> l1=[]
>>> l2=[]
>>> for single_data in repeat:
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(list2) if x == single_data]
    del indices[0]
    for index in indices:
        l1.append(list1[index])
        l2.append(list2[index])


>>> print l1
['e6', 'e3', 'e5']
>>> print l2
['h2', 'h1', 'h1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
list1 = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6', 'e7']
list2 = ['h1', 'h2', 'h1', 'h3', 'h1', 'h2', 'h4']
seen = []
output = []
for index in range(len(list1)):
    if list2[index] not in seen:
        seen.append(list2[index])
    else:
        output.append(list1[index])

print output
```